# set array = one dimension's values of multidimensional object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have an `Array()` of `Object()`s with keys `firstKey` and `secondKey`.

Does a function exist that can set a `var` equal to an `Array()` of all of `firstKey`s' values only?

If so, what is it?  Libs & plugins welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
var newArr = objects.map(function(w){ return w.firstKey; });
```